# Reset Tango Tablet to factory settings

Tags: google-project-tango

Received new Tango tablet, recharged the device. 
At first Power Up the device is locked.
Attempted power up with long press power button and also with power and volume up and/or down.

What is the factory settings sequence ?

Comment: Solved: it was Power Up + Volume Up.

Answer (score 4):

When Device is power off.
Press Power + Volume up + Volume down both at the same time 
till screen turn light.

It should show you the Bootloader Menu
With Options

```
Continue
Fastboot Protocol
Recovery node
Reboot
Power off
Force Recovery
```

For Factory data reset
use Volume "down" and "up" to Recovery node
and press Power key
it will bring you to the Android system recovery screen.